# Is there a shortcut to switch between tabs on Oracle SQL Developer?

Tags: sqldeveloper

I'd like to be able to switch between 'Query Result' windows, and it's a pain having to use a pointer (mouse/touchpad) each time.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> to go to the tab on the left

use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> to go to the tab on the right

Comment: works on version 3.0

Comment: +1 from me, but my opinion is this is _useless knowledge_ :)

Comment: see @chrismarx answer for mac with current version

Comment: I modified to Ctrl+PgUp and Ctrl+PgDn as it was not assigned and most of the browsers support this. :)

Comment: Ah, big help! My question is why Oracle (and IBM) feel the need to make all their UIs so that they don't work/feel like 99% of the other UIs in Windows? I mean, really, why? If it was somehow better, maybe. But it's not, it's worse. I know, I'm barking in the dark here.

Answer (score 9):

You can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> **twice** to switch between tabs in SQL Developer 4.1 on Linux.

Comment: This is exactly I was looking for. I needed to switch between Connections and Worksheets.

Comment: Why twice?! I see you're in the Linux world, but in every other app in Windows-land, Ctrl+Tab (once, yes, just once) is the quick way to navigate through tabs. I guess they do it because they can. :/

Comment: This is true for Windows as well, at least in v19.1

Comment: Does somebody know how to make it work with a single Ctrl+Tab press?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently [no](http://www.scribd.com/doc/7580088/SQL-Developer-Hot-Keys). See if you can create a new shortcut in `Tools > Preferences > Shortcut Keys`.

Comment: What version are you using? My 2.1.1.64 says `Shortcut Keys` instead of `Accelerator`.

Comment: Using 2.1.1.64, the keyboard shortcuts actually works, but in a rather buggy way, and not all tab types (EG, `Query Results`).

Comment: Works great in SQL Developer 4.1.3, this is the way to go. Shift-Cmd-] and [ assigned, as standard.

Answer (score 1):

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> to shift between tabs in sql developer.

Comment: As of which version? The answers above indicate that it's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

For version 3.2 on a Mac, the Shortcut Key you're looking for is

Category:Window

Command:Previous File

By default it's set to Command+F3

Answer (score 0):

It is as @mathias-scheer wrote (use Shift+F5 to go to the tab on the left, use Alt+Shift+F5 to go to the tab on the right) (at least for 3.2.20.xx), but you can also change your shortcuts keys to your own preferences. You do this via Tools/Preferences/Shortcut Keys.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Developer 17.3:

changing tabs to the right is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd>

changing tabs to the left is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd>

A few more shortcuts are available under the

> - Navigate
>
>   - Go to Window >

dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

I have been searching also for a while. In my version now on Windows ( 19.1.0.094 ) the asked for keyboard shortcuts for the

switch between an "SQL Worksheet" and its results ("Query Result") works with 
 <kbd>PAGE UP</kbd> and <kbd>PAGE DOWN</kbd> and